# How to get the full URL from deployed WAR file in a tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, war, tomcat8

I wanted to get the full URL of my war app when I deploy it on the server. 
Let say my application war file is "test.war" and my tomcat installation is on "http://localhost:8080/".

What I want is to get the "http://localhost:8080/test/" value from my Java code inside of this war file, since I have to pass them around to other services.

I am using maven to build the war file, so any maven-specific solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URL: "http://localhost:8080/"
>
> URL: "http://localhost:8080/test/"

Uri: "/test/" in java code

```
String uri = request.getContextPath();
```

Request is class HttpServletRequest 
When deploy server tomcat if file .war with name is ROOT.war --> URL is http://localhost:8080/ 
With file **abc.war** --> URL is http://localhost:8080/abc/ ---> abc is context path

Comment: is it possible to instantiate the HttpServletRequest in your java code within a war file? I tried it out (new HttpServletRequest()) but it requires me to implement a bunch of methods..

Comment: code java : new HttpServletRequest() incorrect ,
HttpServletRequest request in method doGet(HttpServletRequest request) or doPost (HttpServletRequest request ) when use java servlet jsp